# Print the IPMI commands coming from IPMC

Tags: logging, driver, debug-symbols

`IPMI -> Intelligent Platform Management Interface,`
`IPMC -> Intelligent Platform Management Controller`

IPMC is connected to the Processor through a serial cable. The ipmi_serial driver in the kernel communicates with the IPMC to send messages in both directions.

There are 2 types of messages
1. IPMI driver to IPMC -> The driver sends IPMI command and IPMC sends ACK corresponding to it. 
2. IPMC to IPMI driver -> IPMC sends events and driver sends the ACK corresponding to it.

In the driver code, ipmi_serial.c i have enabled the debug flag so that the messages send in the first type is logged.

This is done during runtime as follows.

```
echo 0x06 > /sys/module/ipmi_serial/parameters/debug
```

But for the second types is there a way to enable the messages to be logged?